# how to return a value from JavaScript to pageload function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling my JavaScript function in page load

JScript File:

```
function fnCheckBrowserType()
{
  if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || navigator.appName == "Netscape")
  {
    //document.all["HhdnBrowsertype"].value=navigator.appName 
    document.all["HhdnBrowsertype"].value="1"
    alert(document.getElementById("HhdnBrowsertype").value); 
  }
  else
  {
    //document.getElementById("HhdnBrowsertype").value = navigator.appName 
    document.all["HhdnBrowsertype"].value="0"
    alert(document.getElementById("HhdnBrowsertype").value); 
  }
}
```

ASP.NET code behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "fnCheckBrowserType", "fnCheckBrowserType();", true);

  if (HhdnBrowsertype.Value.ToString() == "1")
  {
    int IE = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    int opera = 0;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<script src="Browsers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <%--<input id="HhdnBrowsertype" type="hidden" name="HhdnBrowsertype" runat="server" />--%>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HhdnBrowsertype" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

In pageload i am calling my javascript  function here  i am setting the hiddden field value  "0" or "1"
 based on the  browser type
 but in page  load HhdnBrowsertype  value is  always  empty

is there anyway from javacript  i return an value  based on that value  i set my hidden   field in page load

Please  help  in me   how  i can return an vlaue "0" or "1" from javscript  to   page load  function

thanks

Comment: Did you checked if HhdnBrowsertype is really the ClientID?

Comment: Aigh! That JavaScript uses insanely ancient browser detection. I'd throw it out and start from scratch. I'd also question the wisdom of having any kind of hidden boolean browser type input. What problem is all this supposed to solve anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it the wrong way.. to do it server side have such code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string browser = Request.Browser.Browser;
   ...
}
```

For IE (all versions) it will return "IE", Chrome will return "Chrome" etc..

Comment: @prince no problem - FYI your post has been made wiki because too many people edited it. To avoid such things put more time to format your questions better in the first place. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the browser type in code behide then use

```
Request.Browser.Browser
```

this will give the browser type like IE